# Sitecore Rocks Stand Alone Installation for 8.2

Tags: sitecore-rocks

Where can i find the Sitecore Rocks Standalone Installation for 8.2.

Note:- i i have the older version and getting the following error

---

### Warning

The Hard Rock Web Service has an unexpected version.

Hard Rock Web Service: 2.1.70.0

Expected version: 1.5.1.8

### Do you want to install the expected version?

### OK   Cancel

Comment: The standalone version was abandoned - but if you really need version 1.5.1.8 as the warning suggests, I found a link to the installer here: http://vsplugins.sitecore.net/sitecore-rocks-windows.ashx (note that I didn't try it).